# How to do check if the datagridview first cell is doubled-click in celldoubleclick?

Tags: vb.net

I want to check if the user is double-clicking the first column on the datagridview and the select command is executed? For example:

```
If datagridview1.rows(e.rowindex).item(0).doubleclicked = true then

some command...

End if
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `CellDoubleClick` handler such as:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        'Do Stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

If you do want the first row as well then `e.RowIndex` is also available.

Comment: What about the row index? This checks just the column itself. To make sure it's the first cell you would need to check both...

Comment: @zaggler looks like OP only asked for "first column", so this solution looks good.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer I was going off title `first cell`... It is missleading as then in the question he said first column.

Comment: @zaggler have added info for row checker in case someone wants it.

Comment: @OSKM I seen that. The question title and question itself contradict each other...

Answer (score 0):

For that you can handel the event `CellContentClick` of your `GridView` as :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
            'some command...
        End If
    End Sub
```